# How to get service callback even if the calling activity is destoyed (in the current activity)

Tags: android, kotlin, service, kotlin-coroutines

This is the situation:

When a user will open a app, he will first see the splsh screen for 5 sec. In this time i want to call a api to get some data and just give it to my Splash Screen Activity and then i will pass it to the login activity. If it failed to get the data in 5 sec i want it to continue fatching the data  in background  then send the data directly to the login activity

How can i do so using services or coroutines in android?

Comment: Its depends of your needs. You can use service and bind current activity to it to get updates or use WorkManager.

Comment: Can you please suggest the solution depending on the situation that I have mentioned above I just a new in this field

Comment: Ok, so if you want to download data right at the call, you will have to use service because WorkManager could have some delay to call it. About the service, if data should be downloaded only if the app is alive and in foreground you can just use service. If it should work until data is downloaded even if app is closed you will have to use foreground service. To get data from service you can use broadcast receiver or binder.

Comment: If it's ok can please show me the code?

Comment: Sorry but i do not have time to prepare solution for you. You have all keywords to start doing it. Just try to do it and if there will be a problem with your code, update the question and someone will help you.